# Do function before submit of form - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I do a function when the user submits a form and then continue. My code is:

```
$("textarea.edit").parent().submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("textarea.edit", this).val("Hello");
    $(this).submit();
});
```

But it didn't work??

Comment: how does your html markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the second `.submit()` as it is already in the method. Removing this, you should also remove the `.preventDefault()` method.

```
<form>
    <textarea class="edit">Text</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("textarea.edit").parent().submit(function(){
        $("textarea.edit").val("Hello");
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
$("textarea.edit").parent().submit(function(e){
    $("textarea.edit", this).val("Hello");
});
```

I just removed the `e.preventDefault();` and `$(this).submit();` lines.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); will prevent default action that is submitting form. it should work :)

Comment: The original code wasn't working because of the `e.preventDefault();` along with the `$(this).submit();` -- it was basically an infinite loop and never submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    if(bla bla){
        return false;
    } else {
        bla bla 
        return true; 
    }
})
```

Comment: What are the two cases of "bla bla"? Would you add some explanation as to what you expect the OP to substitute here?